# Python: Speed up re.sub to redact files (multi-processing doesn't help)

Tags: python, regex, performance

I need to redact certain words from several thousand files. There's a separate reference file of about 50,000 words that need to be redacted from the files.

With the code I've written, the process is going to take weeks, and I need to make it faster.

```
import glob, re, sys
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def redact_file(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()

        for word in words_to_redact:
            search_term = r"(?:\b)"+word+r"(?:\b)"
            data = re.sub(search_term, '#', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE)  #this seems to be the slow bit?

    with open(file+'_REDACTED', 'w') as file:
        file.write(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    words_to_redact = []
    with open ("words_to_redact.txt") as myfile:    #about 50,000 rows in this reference file
        words_to_redact=myfile.read().splitlines()

    input_files = glob.glob("input_*.txt")

    pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) 
    pool.map(redact_file, input_files)
```

Using multi-processing doesn't seem to help.

I think the performance issue comes from calling re.sub 50,000 times for each file.  Because this creates a new copy of the "data" string every iteration, I think the process becomes limited by memory/cache speed.

I think I have to use re.sub because using regEx is the only way to match words.

Is there a way to do re.sub without a copy each time, or some other way to make this faster?

Comment: Have you tried generating a single regular expression containing all of the words: `search_term = r"\b(word1|word2|word3|...|word50000)\b"`?

Answer (score 4):

1. use `re.compile()` to compile your pattern once, and not every time you perform the search
2. put all your words into a large pattern.

Then your code might look like this:

```
import re

words_to_redact = [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', etc...] # load 'em from file

patt = re.compile( r"(?:\b)(" + '|'.join( words_to_redact ) + r")(?:\b)" )

patt.sub( .. )  # you know what to do, need to call this only once (no loop)
```

Comment: Unless the Python dialect of regular expressions is very strange, you need to use round brackets rather than square brackets. Otherwise you're generating a giant character class.